# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have already checked the other entries on `StackOverflow`, but it did not help.

I am building a `RESTapi` with `node.js`, and I am using `MongoDB` with `mongoose`
I have a `Schema` that contains three different models. I am able to save `POST` request to the entry. I am sure that entry is saved because I checked on `atlas.mongo`. However, I have a problem when I am trying to use `GET` request.

It gives this error:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model

These are my **Models**: (These models are in different files)

```
const Model1 = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    word1: { type: [String], require: true }
});
----------------------------------------------
const Model2 = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    word2: { type: [String], require: true }
});
----------------------------------------------
const Model3 = mongoose.Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   element1: { type: [String],  default: ""},
   element2: { type: [String], default: ""}
});
----------------------------------------------
const Word = mongoose.Schema({
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   md3: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Model3', require: true },
   md2: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Model2', require: true },
   md1: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, ref: 'Model1', require: true }
});
```

This is my **POST** request:

```
exports.entry_create = (req, res, next) => {
const newModel3 = new Model3({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    element1: req.body.element1,
    element2: req.body.element2
});

const newModel2 = new Model2({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    word2: req.body.word2
});

const newModel1 = new Model1({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    word1: req.body.word1
});

const newEntry = new Word({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    md3: newModel3,
    md2: newModel2,
    md1: newModel1
});

newEntry
    .save(); // i have also then() and catch() part
};
```

This is where I got the error on `Postman`

```
exports.entry_get_all = (req, res, next) => {
Word.find()
    .select('_id md3 md2 md1')
    .populate('md3')
    .populate('md2')
    .populate('md1')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        res.status(200).json({
            numOfEntries: docs.length,
            Entries: docs.map(doc => {
                return {
                    _id: doc._id,
                    md3: doc.md3,
                    md2: doc.md2,
                    md1: doc.md1,
                    request: { type: 'GET' }
                }
            })
        });
    }); // i have also catch() part
};
```

What could be the problem? Is `_id`'s of `md3, md2 & md1` returns `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it has to do with your references md1, md2 and md3. The way you reference another model is by the _id, which in your case it's and ObjectId. That being said, when you define md1, md2, and md3 you say the type is mixed, not an ObjectId. Do this instead:

```
const Word = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  md3: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Model3', require: true },
  md2: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Model2', require: true },
  md1: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Model1', require: true }
});
```

Also note: You don't need to explicitly create a new ObjectId when creating an instance of your model. If using mongoose, it creates the _id for you! So you can just create a new `Word` like this:

```
let md1 = null;
let md2 = null;
let md3 = null;

const newModel3 = new Model3({
  element1: req.body.element1,
  element2: req.body.element2
});

// Save newModel3
newModel3.save()
.then((_md3) => {
  md3 = _md3;

  const newModel2 = new Model2({
    word2: req.body.word2
  });

  return newModel2.save();
})
.then((_md2) => {
  md2 = _md2;

  const newModel1 = new Model1({
    word1: req.body.word1
  });

  return newModel1.save();
})
.then((_md1) => {
  md1 = _md1

  const newEntry = new Word({
    md3: md3._id,
    md2: md2._id,
    md1: md1._id
  });

  return newEntry.save();
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and `md3, md2 & md1` returns null when `GET` request used

Comment: Ahhh you also have the call `newModel3.save()`, `newModel2.save()` and `newModel1.save() `prior to saving your Word. Without saving them to the database, you cannot use references

Comment: Ahhhh, so I can't use them without saving individually to database?

Comment: Correct. I'd recommend saving them in order, chaining the promises.